# Can't install barman-cli due to Requires: python-boto3

Tags: centos, rhel

When install `barman-cli` on the RHEL OS:

```
sudo yum install barman-cli -y
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: barman-cli-2.10-2.el7.noarch (2ndquadrant-dl-default-release-pg10)
           Requires: python-boto3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Tried to install `boto3` by pip:

```
$ pip install boto3
```

Then install barman-cli again, the same result.

OS Information:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.7 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.7"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.7:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.7
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.7"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you're trying to install [barman-cli](https://github.com/2ndquadrant-it/barman-cli) from a [3rd party repository](https://repmgr.org/docs/4.4/installation-packages.html), which is fine, but this repository doesn't provide all the dependencies that `barman-cli` requires.

You could contact the [upstream provider](https://github.com/2ndquadrant-it/barman-cli) for help, since they are responsible to deliver the required packages, but according to their Github page `barman-cli` has been merged into [barman core](https://github.com/2ndquadrant-it/barman).

While the installation could be forced with various switches (as shown in the error message above) I'd recommend to contact upstream about this and/or check if the [installation instructions](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.10/#installation-on-redhatcentos-using-rpm-packages) or repository URL has been changed.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Your point is very right.